# SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: Failed loading libpng16-16.dll: The specified module could not be found

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have spent the last hour trying to find a fix for this error. I have searched all over SO and other sites for answers but nothing that I have found has worked so far. So here I am, in desperate need of help.

First of here are the versions of software and libraries that I am using:

- SDL2-2.0.12
- SDL2_image-2.0.5
- VS Community 2019

Here is my code for the area that messes up:

```
bool CApp::OnInit() {

if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) 
{
    printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}
else {

    std::cout << "SDL was initialized!!!" << std::endl;
}

// The window for the game.
Surf_Window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Window",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    screenWidth, screenHeight,
    0);

if (Surf_Window == NULL)
{
    return false;
}
else {

    std::cout << "Main Window was initialized!!!" << std::endl;
    //Initialize PNG loading
    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    if (!(IMG_Init(imgFlags) & imgFlags))
    {
        printf("SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    else
    {

        std::cout << "SDL_image was initialized!!!" << std::endl;
        //Get window surface
        Surf_Display = SDL_GetWindowSurface(Surf_Window);

        if (Surf_Display == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// Fill the window with White color.
SDL_FillRect(Surf_Display, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(Surf_Display->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));

// The image surface we load.
const char* image = "data/images/bgHomeScreen.bmp";
Surf_Test = CApp::OnLoad("data/images/bgHomeScreen.bmp");
//CSurface::OnLoad(Surf_Test, image);

if (Surf_Test == NULL) 
{
    printf("Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", "data/images/bgHomeScreen.bmp", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}

SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(Surf_Window);

SDL_Delay(2000);

return true;
```

}

Here are images of my Project settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am looking to fix this error so that I can continue to learn the uses of SDL2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I added all of the dependencies from the `SDL2-2.0.12\lib\x86` to my projects Release and Debug directories and the program ran as expected. Just remember to copy the x64 folder instead of x86 if you plan on using 64 bit.